# Sending upstream message to GCM from Android app

Tags: android, xampp, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send some data to GCM. I have configured xampp in my local server to accomplish that.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                        String msg = "";
                        try {
                            Bundle data = new Bundle();
                            String msgId = "001";
                            data.putString("myid", id);
                            data.putString("mylt", la);
                            data.putString("myln", lo);
                            data.putString("recid", recid);

                            gcm.send(recid+ "@gcm.googleapis.com", msgId, data);
                        } catch (IOException ioexce) {
                            ioexce.printStackTrace();
                            msg = ioexce.toString();
                            Log.e("gcm_error", msg);
                        }
                        return msg;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {

                    }
                }.execute(null, null, null);
```

Per [the docs the parameters in the send method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#send%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20long,%20android.os.Bundle%29) are, String to, String msgId, Bundle data. I used the token the receiver received when they register with GCM in place of String to. But I get "W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10011" in the log when I execute the above code and the message is not sent to my server. Upon some research I found out the "found 10011" meant some parameter is missing. But I don't know what is missing.

Comment: can you post the actual request and response? or the actual logs?

Comment: I got the same message on Logcat, do you have found something else since you posted your question ?